# Is there a word for replacing foreign words with English substitutes?

Tags: word-choice

On tonight's broadcast of NPR's *All Things Considered*, host Robert Siegel [interviewed Ralph Keyes](http://www.npr.org/2014/01/29/268404364/time-to-retire-these-imported-words-but-how-to-replace-them), who "writes about words for *American Scholar* magazine." The topic was a contest run by the magazine to find suitable English replacement words (neologisms, in this case) for four words which have been borrowed into English but have entered common parlance to varying degrees: mensch, frisson, schadenfreude, and sympatico/sympathique.

While the proposed neologisms were on the whole underwhelming, I did come to wonder:  is there a word for the conscious replacement of foreign words with English substitutes, either as an editorial action in a specific work or as a broader, sociolinguistics endeavor?  'Anglicization' came to mind, but I think of that more with respect to spelling or pronunciation (*i.e.*, not wholesale word replacement).  Is there a term for this process?

(Incidentally, isn't it the French who have a semi-governmental process to guard against foreign word borrowings, at least as far as the official language,mwhatever that means, is concerned?  If so,mother obviously 'anglicization' can't be right, assuming this French body performs a similar effort to replace foreign words with French alternatives, officially or un....)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise

Comment: Indeed, *c'est L'Acedémie Française*. :-). They've been accused of being a.k.a. The Department of Curmudgeons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But English doesn't need nor tend to [Englishize](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800619.001.0001/acref-9780192800619-e-428) foreign words. Not any more. Or much less so than in the past.

Think of the relatively new Italian words adopted by English: *cappuccinos; latte; espresso; paparazzi; la dolce vita*; and *simpatico*. They're easy to pronounce, they need no explanations, they make the speaker sound cultured and worldly.

Why would English speakers prefer to say: *white coffees with froth*; *milky strong coffee* (actually in Italian it's "milk"); *very fast reduced black coffee*; *freelance press photographers who hound celebrities*; *the sweet life*; and *nice*?

> **Englishize/Englishise**; 1 To make English in manner or in language: ‘the
>   Englishised Indian’ (Blackwood's Magazine, 1922).

[image]
[image]

[Concise Oxford Companion to the English Language](http://books.google.it/books?id=QMsWFsI0YkIC&pg=PT563&dq=Englishize&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m4HrUpbxBYTChAfExIDIDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Englishize&f=false)

Plus I discovered another reference dated 1813 which suggests that the term *Englishise* is not so fanciful or so recent as suggested by @fumblefingers in the comments below. The book is entitled:

> *Historical and descriptive Accounts of the Ancient and Present State
>   of Ragland Castle.* By Charles Heath.  The sixth edition.

[image]

Therefore, it appears that the term Englishize (or englishis/ze) although less common than Anglicize, is accepted and is a more than valid alternative.

Comment: Let's face it, *Englishise* is just a facetious nonce-word. The established term (recorded in OED since at least 1710) is **anglicize** - *verb, trans. To borrow or render (a word, phrase, etc.) into English*

Comment: Is chipottle a foreign word?

Comment: Now would the downvoter care to justify his/her downvote. As I have always done so, more often than not and to help the user to *improve* the answer.

Comment: *Englishize*, "To adapt towards English" seems from these definitions to be a term applied only to non-English languages. And @BlessedGeek: I would say *chipotle* is still very much a foreign word, being Mexican Spanish and originating in Nahuatl. It may in future be anglicised, in which case *chipottle* to reflect English pronunciation is a distinct possibility.

Comment: @TimLymington Yes, I think you may be right. I became a bit fixed on the word itself and didn't interpret the definition (on the 2nd reference) clearly. The third one seems valid enough though. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a word, but there is a belief called [linguistic purity in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_English) that advocates for the use of native English words over foreign ones. Foreign words can be translated into English, creating a [calque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) that is derived from the other language. Interestingly, the Wikipedia article notes that "calque" itself comes from French.

Comment: Linguistic Purity sounds insane. Where would you stop. If you take it to the extreme what would be left? IIRC, Almost all words ending in -tion were imported from French, for example.

Comment: "English purism": http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2014/01/english-purism

Comment: @Colin, you'd end up with Icelandic, basically.

Comment: It's called *suicidal linguistic tendencies*.

Comment: @Hugo Yes, that article from The Economist is interesting. But I didn't really see the point about the literalness of some German words e.g. 'Fernseher' (far-seer). What does 'television' mean, if not 'far-seer'?

Comment: Yes, but it means it in German instead of Greek. This apparently matters to some. Another term beside _calque_ is _loan translation_. As for English Purity, see [William Barnes' 1878 _An Outline of English Speech-Craft_](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=K60VAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y), which is a grammar of English without loan words.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, why suicidal? Icelandic gets on quite well with it, saying _tölva_ instead of _kompjúter_, _þyrla_ instead of _helíkopter_, and (perhaps somewhat tongue-twistingly) _rannsóknarlögreglumaður_ instead of _detektívur_.

Comment: At least Icelandic has a smaller population of speakers. Americans and Brits can't even agree on spelling or vocabulary for the same things!